# Allow the user to create new tableViewCells with text from a label in a different viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

So, in viewController1 I have a textfield and a "save-button" and when a user presses the "save-button", the text is saved in a label underneath (on the same viewcontroller).

I wan't the user to be able to click another button (Get started!), which should lead him/her to the next viewcontroller, which is a UITableViewController. This button should also create a new cell in the tableViewController - with the saved text from the label in viewController1.

I have used the "prepare(for segue:"-function, which works fine to pass the data on to the next viewController, but for some reason, I can only add it to a label outside the tableView-cells. How do I add the text to a label inside the tableView-cells?

And how do I make the user create a new cell in the tableView at the same time?

In viewController1:

```
@IBOutlet weak var DiaryNameLabel: UILabel!

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PassingDiaryName" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! DiariesTableView
        vc.name = DiaryNameLabel.text!
    }
}
```

In viewController2 (The tableViewController):

```
class DiariesTableView: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var NameLabel: UILabel!

var name:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NameLabel.text = name
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Diary1", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = NameLabel.text
    return cell
}
```

So, as I said, this current code works fine to pass the text from the label in viewController1 onto the UILabel, NameLabel, in the next viewController. But once I set this label inside a cell, I get the error:

> The NameLabel outlet from the DiariesTableView to the UILabel is
>   invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Thanks upfront!

Comment: Think about how your first cell was created. Now think about how you can have two cells. (Don't worry about button clicks and all now). Now think about three (Change the code to see this happen). So now you see a pattern right? Now change that logic in the pattern into code and implement it in button action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre getting it all wrong. Which is fine since you are new I suppose.

Heres what you need to do:

When you press save you need to preserve the text into some sort of a holder, array for example. Then you need to pass that array to the next view controller, where you would use it as a data source for the table. If all your connections are fine it will show up on your table as you would expect it to.

Comment: Haha, I don't doubt that I'm getting it all wrong - I'm trying my best though!

Just to understand your little guide there; how would I pass this array from viewController1 to the tableViewController? Just using segues? Or is some other method better?

And what do I display it in - in the tableView? As I wrote, Xcode tends to give me an error, when I try to just add a label to my custom tabelViewCell. So should I just make this work somehow - or is it because there is another way to display text in a tableViewCell?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry I shouldnt have said "all wrong" but ofcourse things can get better :). Lets get this working. Well you would pass the array the same way your passing the string in the code shared above in the question. Just as your defining var name:String = "" in your tableview controller you would define an array. Just like you assign vc.name = DiaryNameLabel.text! in first viewcontroller you would now assign the newly contructed array.

Comment: I don't believe you need @IBOutlet weak var NameLabel: UILabel! in DiariesTableView. To show the content to would just need cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]. Where array is obviously what you pass on from viewcontroller one

Comment: Btw this way of passing the content is called Dependency Injection. Also there are couple of more mays to achieve the same such as delegation and notification patterns.

Comment: Wauw! I think you are actually making things work!! I come across another problem now though... The text I need to display is several lines. In a normal label, I know how to just add "lines" in the Utilities Bar, but now that the text is shown in a so called "Content View" or a tableViewCell, I don't know how to get it to display several lines in one cell?

Comment: Good to hear of the progress. Where you have mentioned cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row] i.e cellForRow Method. Try setting cell!.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0 and then add following function
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

Comment: You are a f*cking genious! I would have never figured that out by myself. Do you know if I have to change the text-layout programmatically too? If I fx. wan't it to be bigger and more like a headline? - Cause this Content View has none of the normal options of a label in the utilities bar.

Comment: I dont usually use Storyboarding or XIB so am not aware of Utility bar. But hey try this cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline). Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: maybe you are looking at the wrong place. instead of looking at the content view which is basically the base view of the cell. try traversing the properties of textLabel, which is a UILabel.

Comment: Haha Thanks btw :D

Comment: Yeah. Thanks - looks better now. Please let me know if I'm taking too much advantage of your expertise right now! - But this cell that is now well-created with the right name and all, does not stick around for long! Only if I move to the next viewController, it is still there, when i press "Back". But if I move around from a couple different ones, and enter the tableViewController again from a "different angle", the cell is gone... It will probably be gone too, when the app is closed, I suppose. Why is this? And how to solve the problem? :/

Comment: Not an issue mate! I am here to help. Notice this line -> 
 let vc = segue.destination as! DiariesTableView
 vc.array = someArray. What you are essentially doing here is you are instantiating a new DiariesTableView and assigning your reference array to it. Maybe when your are accessing it from a "different angle" you are not assigning the reference array to it. However things work fine when you press back  because the DiariesTableView still exists in the navigation stack and has not been released by the memory, so it shows up as it was.

Comment: The way to solve this is to have a persistent storage. You might wanna read up CoreData, File Storage or even NSUserDefaults Options are many but best option is something you need to decide keeping you application requirement in mind. The thing is persistent storage works even when you kill the app

Comment: I see. That makes sense. I have already tried to get a hold of NSUserDefault a couple of times, but all blogs and tutorials on the topic seems quite complicated for a newbie like me - that was why I tried to use segues instead - but ofcourse... No short cuts allowed, when it comes to programming! :D  

So, does what you just wrote, mean that there is no way of getting this Dependency Injection to store the data, when killing the app? I need to go to some sort of persistent storage in order to achieve this?

Comment: That is correct. You would require a persistent storage if you want data integrity. As far as I know segues have never been a mode to store information rather they are a mechanism to transition from one view controller to another. Think of dependency injection as a mode to transfer data not as preserver/storer of that data. Also dont get overwhelmed good things come slow.

Comment: I hope that is it :D. If you think this answer assisted you in achieving what you wanted to achieve please do not forget to mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this error("*The NameLabel outlet from the DiariesTableView to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content*.") happens because you connect NameLabel with UILabel in dynamic tableView cell. 
You need to subclass UITableViewCell and bind name label there.
Something like this:

```
final class YourCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
}
```

and in cellForRow func:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Diary1", for: indexPath) as! YourCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = NameLabel.text
    return cell
}
```

OR if you don't need dynamic table view, you can use "Static cells":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbJZS.png)

With static cells you can make outlet in your ViewController and you don't need implement UITableViewDataSource, just add in XCode UI Builder. But with Static cells you can't insert or remove cells from tableView

In your case you need store array of string somewhere that enter user:

```
class TextStorage {
    func save(text: String) {
        // save somewhere example NSUserDefaults or CoreData
    }

    func obtainText() -> [String] {
        // obtain saved text
    }
}
```

The viewContoller with textfield will be like this. Text :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    private let textSorage = TextStorage()

    @IBAction func done() {
        textStorage.save(text: textField.text ?? "")
        // then go to viewController with tableView
    }
}
```

ViewController with table view just obtain saved text from storage and show it in tableView:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    private let textSorage = TextStorage()
    private var savedText: [String]?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        updateTableView()
    }

    func updateTableView() {
        savedText = textSorage.obtainText()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension TableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Diary1", for: indexPath) as! YourCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = NameLabel.text
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return savedText?.count ?? 0
    }
}
```